# Code without "messing up everything"?

Tags: php

I'm a coder (I'm on a mac) and I'm using a computer that is a computer that "shouldn't be messed with".  I'd like to install some command-line programs but I want to somehow be able to erase everything I did.

I know, I shouldn't be doing any of that just-in-case something does happen.

But, I'd like to do all of my work and then have it automatically completely clean everything up when I'm finished.

I'm planning to code in php, java and maybe objective-c (Apple developer toolkit).  I installed another OS (dual boot) and yeah.  That didn't go over very well with the manager....

Comment: This depends entirely on what operating system you're using. If it's Windows, I have no idea how you'd go about doing that. If it were any other system (meaning a Unix-clone), I'd simply download them to my user's home directory, keep them there and delete them afterward.

Also, you might suggest to your employers that you can't realistically be expected to work on a system that "shouldn't be messed with" - a workstation needs to be messed with.

Comment: Have you considered virtual machine?

Comment: Might be good to know what you are trying to code. Is it c++, c# etc. So people can help you find the correct tools or ide

Comment: I updated the question from the feedback that I received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has anyone just said "Live OS"?

Many applications can be installed on a USB stick, see [portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps). (Windows only.)

If that doesn't suit your needs, download a Ubuntu image, burn that on a CD and tell your target computer to boot from this CD. E voila, now you have a complete OS at your hand, that doesn't leave any trace on the target computer. (Make sure to save your data on a *real* hard drive or USB stick before shutting down the computer.)

On a Mac, since it's a Unix, you could install another OS X inside a chroot environment. However, I doubt, that it will suit your needs as to leave the original system untouched, since you seem to have to install lots of other stuff to get this running: http://www.algonet.se/~afb/mac/chroot.html (Google for OS X and chroot, perhaps there is a cleaner solution).

Finally you can use a virtual machine. Download VirtualBox, create a machine, use it, and the remove it and uninstall VirtualBox.

Comment: I updated the question to include that my system is "mac" so I won't be able to use portableapps.com because they are PC apps.  I also cannot use another system because I'm not allowed :(

Answer (score 5):

If it's fairly modern machine with decent amount of RAM, you could run a virtual machine with another OS in it. This way you're for all purposes sandboxed.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a virtual machine and install the OS you want to code in in it. When you're down you can delete the OS first, then uninstall the virtual machine, then you can probably do a system restore to clean it off completely. I personally use VMWare. Its pretty easy to install a new OS in it and it has good networking features.

VMWare Link [http://downloads.vmware.com/](http://downloads.vmware.com)

You can check out some here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtual_machines

Comment: And don't forget VirtualBox, which is quite good and free/opensource. Personally I've liked VirtualBox better than VMWare, even.

Comment: If I install virtual box, and I uninstall it, will there be no remains?  E.g settings, invisible files, reverts changes to system files

Comment: Probably, I'm not sure, that's why I suggested a system restore after you uninstall. And set a system restore checkpoint before you install the VM.

Answer (score 1):

My best recommendation would be to use a Linux live CD and save your data onto a USB flash drive.  Boot the live CD (if you can select the machine's boot device), do what you need to do, save your data, and shut down.

Some examples -- many more are out there...

- [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/get-fedora)
- [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html) (the "classic" liveCD distribution)
- [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of this machine? Is it in a state that SHOULD NEVER BE CHANGED? Or does it get changed on a regular basis, just not by you?

If it doesn't get changed, and only provides services you could look at software like DeepFreeze. It's a program that my school used to use, it basically sets up an "Image" of the disc, and everytime the computer is reboot it restores that image.

http://www.faronics.com/ <-- I think this it the site, I can't visit it because my company's firewall blocks it... hmmm

Answer (score 0):

I have a flash drive with utilities, including [pathman.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657) and a batch file that adds the utilities to the path. Unplug the flash, log out, and they're all gone. Note that this could leave traces, e.g. in the event log or antivirus logs, or be logged by any software that's monitoring activity.

Edit:
Mac, huh? You could apply the same idea, utilities on a flash, script to put them in your path.